# WPF/C#: A WebView / Browser component to show local pages and handle outgoing requests internally

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, chromium, cefsharp

**What I'm looking for:**
I'm looking for a way to show a local located webpage containing CSS and JS in a WPF application. But the tricky part, it should also be possible to **CATCH AND PROCESS** outgoing requests.
So I need to catch GetRequest, process them myself, and return the answer myself.

[image: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArLDiUd-U5dtg01y_jvotFDEZNKE]

**Why:**
I have a pretty extensive UI for a server based application. (HTML/CSS/JS) So I have the choice between completely remake the whole UI in WPF or I need to find a way to use this HTML based UI in a WPF application. While showing the UI works fine with most components I found so far, catching request and then providing my own answer as JSON on the other hand seems to be a tricky thing.

**The two I tried so far:**

- WebView control for Windows Forms and WPF [WebView Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview)
  but this doesn't support catching outgoing request as far as I have seen.
- CefSharp (Chromium): Does support catching and redirecting, but I can't answer the request my self it seems? [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

Does any of you know of any component/framework that could do that?

**EDIT**
CefSharp project: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArLDiUd-U5dtg06kzBSMOqDZLWxJ?e=Mdkchd

Comment: Have you tried to use some library to be a webproxy? Like [TitaniumWebProxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy) to "monitor" specific Url/path and do wherever you want like reply a redirect to any local address or event apply another Respose.

Comment: In CefSharp you can intercept a request and provide your own response,  http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_IResourceRequestHandler_GetResourceHandler.htm See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31367169/4583726 for an example ResourceRequestHandler implementation. See also http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_ResourceHandler.htm I'd need to know more details before I could say anything specific about your use case.

Comment: @amaitland I tried to do it with cefsharp. I got it to redirect a request and even to change a response to some degree. But how do I fake a response when the get request goes to an address that doesn't exist? The application has to work offline. 
I uploaded a C# project with the CefSharp Code I got in case you want to take a look.

Comment: @aimaitland I maybe need to add: The reason for that, the application gets some data for populating UI elements through a get request. But since it has to be offline, I need to catch the request and just answer with my own JSON.

Comment: Website doesn't need to exist, sounds like a scheme handler might be the go for you. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler

Comment: @amaitland thanks, I'll give it a try and report back as soon as I know more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised the solution I got at the end:

The javascript calls a webpage that doesn't exist. The Request & Resource Handler catch this call and return their own anwser. When you implement your own Request/Resource handler, you have to replace the NotImplementedException in some cases even if you don't need the functionality. Just visit the offical documentation for the default behaviour in this case: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_IRequestHandler.htm

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Chromium.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        ...
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser
            x:Name="ChromiumWebBrowser"
            />    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ChromiumWebBrowser.BrowserSettings.WebSecurity = CefState.Disabled;
    ChromiumWebBrowser.RequestHandler = new RequestHandler();
    ChromiumWebBrowser.Address = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "TestHtml", "index.html");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <button onclick="call()">Call</button>
</body>
```

**JS Script**

```
function call() {
    axios.get('http://doesnt_exist')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        });
}
```

**Request Handler**

```
public class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    public IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetResourceRequestHandler " + request.Url);
        return new ResourceRequestHandler();
    }
...
}
```

**ResourceRequestHandler**

```
class ResourceRequestHandler : IResourceRequestHandler
{
    public IResourceHandler GetResourceHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetResourceHandler " + request.Url);
        if (request.Url.Contains("doesnt_exist"))
            return ResourceHandler.FromString("Hello");
        return null;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to implement every interface method then there are default implementations for IRequestHandler and IResourceRequestHandler, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250797/chromium-send-custom-header-info-on-initial-page-load-c-sharp/31367169#31367169 has an example.

Comment: If you wish to serve local files from disk then there is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_SchemeHandler_FolderSchemeHandlerFactory.htm See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler for details on that option